# Web UI bind html element with observeable variable in server-side code

Tags: dart, dart-webui

Is it possible to data-bind a html field (2way binding or 1way binding) to a observeable variable that is declered in some server-side code?

Would be awesome if you could change the value of one variable on the server-side and all clients get updated that one specific html field.

Comment: Short answer no. Long answer: No but you can bind it to a variable which is updated regularly by an ajax call. All clients should be running the same version of your script so will receive the updates. More immediate responses can be used by a variable which is updated through a websocket connection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no built-in way to do this as it involves dealing with a bunch of things like networking and serialization.

I am building an application where the server side framework sends data notifications to all clients via WebSockets. The data is automatically serialized/deserialized so that my views can listen to a stream of data notifications and act on them.

So, in essence, when data is modified on the server either automatically or by request of a client, the changes are propagated to every client in real-time. However, the clients decide if they are interested in the data notification and only so they will retrieve the updated information.

Give it a shot and try to write something and come back with any specific problems you might face.

Comment: your application sounds interesting. Can you provide a link?